# Asp.NET - Multiple Instances of AdRotator

Tags: asp.net

I've created a master page that uses 3 instances of System.Web.UI.WebControls.AdRotator each backed by the same XML file of ad elements. For example,

```
<asp:adRotator AdvertisementFile="/ads.xml" Runat="server"/>

*** ads.xml ***
<Advertisements>  
  <Ad>
      <ImageUrl>/Path/Banner.gif</ImageUrl>
      <NavigateUrl>http://www.google.com</NavigateUrl>
      <AlternateText>
         The best search engine in the world!
       </AlternateText>
      <Impressions>3</Impressions>
   </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```

The problem is on occasion the same ad will appear in 2 or more of the AdRotators at a given instant.

What's the best way to make the ads presented at any given time unique? One possibility is to separate the ads into 3 distinct XML files and assign each AdRotator a different file. However, that leads to a given ad always being in the same location that may or my not be the "premium" location on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AdRotator wasn't designed to display a series of banners, so you can't prevent duplicates if you place multiple AdRotator controls on a Web Form and point them to the same AdvertisementFile.

The AdRotator is only designed to serve the *most* basic ad functionality. It's definitely not intended to compete with or replace a "real" ad-serving system. If you need anything more elaborate, you'll need to look into a third-party system or roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

Although I second Rex M's recommendation of rolling out your own AdRotator because of its inherent limitations, there is a way to do this within the AdCreatedEvent of the rotator. For 3 or more rotators try the concept outlined at http://tinyurl.com/7rymect (must scroll to bottom of page to see answer).  Otherwise, you could try something along these lines with 2 AdRotators on the page:

```
/// <summary>
/// First ad rotator control
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void AdRotator_AdCreated(object sender, AdCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get displayed ad's id
    int currentAd = (int)e.AdProperties["AdId"];

    //Remove that ad from the list
    TList<Banner> ads = GetBannerThatIsNotThisAdId(currentAd, AdRotator.KeywordFilter);

    //Do we have an ad to display?
    if (ads.Count > 0)
    {
        AdRotator1.DataSource = ads;
        AdRotator1.DataBind();
    }
    else //nope, so hide 2nd control
    {
        AdRotator1.Visible = false;
    }
}

public static TList<Banner> GetBannerThatIsNotThisAdId(int adId, string pCategory)
{
    BannerService bannerService = new BannerService();
    TList<Banner> banners = bannerService.GetAll();
    Banner banner = bannerService.GetByAdId(adId);

    banners.ApplyFilter(delegate(Banner b) { return b.Keyword.Equals(pCategory) && (b.IsActive.Equals(true)); });

    banners.Remove(banner);

    return banners;
}
```